# WKWebView delegate method error message

Tags: wkwebview

I am using WKWebView to load and display the content of a web site. After the app was launched and running, the delegate method -webView:didFailNavigation:withError:got called. Following is the error description (error.description) extracted from this delegate method using Xcode debugger:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=}

I did some Google search and found that Code=-999 is caused by ErrorCancelled, meaning another request is made before the previous request is completed. So how should I fix this issue in my app? Thanks a lot in advance.